# Connecting to linux-server with Remmina RDP gives error: Unable to establish a connection RDP server <server>

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, remote-desktop, remmina

I have been trying to connect remotely to the server of my department using Remmina (my OS is Linux). I am able to connect to it via the terminal using SSH (ssh user@ip_adress). As the work I am supposed to do is relatively complex for me, I am trying to connect to the server with a more user-friendly interface (as if I am working on my own laptop).

I have been working on other servers via Remmina (but only with SSH) for similar purposes, but this is the first time I am trying to set up an RDP-connection.

Using SSH on the terminal, I would first connect to the university using Cisco, and then connect via "ssh username@ipadress".

In Remmina, I am entering:

```
protocol: RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol


server: ipadress 
user name: username
user password: mypassword
```

I end up with the error:

> Unable to establish a connection to RDP server -ipadress-

I have browsed online for some time, but couldn't find anything related to my issue:

- I tried to set the "Security" settings to "RDP" (I also tried with TLS, and others).
- Keeping the "Enable SSH tunnel" unselected has not helped.

I want to mention that I don't have sudo priviliges on the server.

I was hoping that someone could help me with the following:

1. Do I need to prepare/setup anything on the server before connection from my laptop?
2. Is the way I entered the information into Remmina okay?
3. What would be a good way to proceed from here on? I started trying to connect with Remmina, but is there maybe a better option?

Answer (score 1):

RDP is a Windows Remote Desktop Protocol. Linux servers do not support it by default. You might be able to use VNC or NX, but you would need to verify that with the server's system administrators. They would have had to install some type of graphical user interface.